# PDF of function of gamma distribution

Tags: density-function, gamma-distribution

If $X = {X_1, \dots, X_n}$ is a sample of independent and identically distributed random variables, each following a Gamma distribution $\Gamma(2, λ)$, with unknown scale parameter $\lambda$, then, how do we find the pdf of $Y_i = \lambda X_i$?

Comment: You have to apply the [change of variable formula](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_26/reference-manual/change-of-variables-section.html)

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.